# What JavaScript engine does the TypeScript compiler use on Windows?

Tags: typescript

I installed the editor plugin and these are the installed files:

[image: TypeScript files]

I'm just curious as to how the compiler works and if anyone could give an overview of these files?

1. There are also two JavaScript files where I expected only one, what
   do they do (one must be the compiler)? *is tsc the compiler and typescript the syntax parser?*
2. Does tsc.exe use the Chakra engine?
3. What is the intelligence written in? *What is the lib file
   for? (actually I can answer this one it's the documentation for the
   ECMAScript APIs)*

Comment: given it's M$ who created this, could be C#, could be VC++. you could just OPEN the js files and look, since typescript compiles directly to standard JS anyways.

Comment: Yeah I did, it's a bit hard to tell.. I thought I'd see if anyone already knew. However that's only half the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There are also two JavaScript files where I expected only one, what do they do (one must be the compiler)? is tsc the compiler and typescript the syntax parser?

tsc.js is the command-line compiler used by tsc.exe. Both typescript.js and tsc.js are largely identical but tsc.js has the command-line options parser and batch compiler needed for the command-line compile. typescript.js is just the core compiler.

> What is the intelligence written in?

In TypeScript.

> What is the lib file for?

It is the type description of the JavaScript runtime.

Comment: Yes, where's the source for tsc.exe?